# Selling shoes of the right size

Tags: python, programming-challenge, python-3.x

This is a question from HackerRank. I have solved it and want to know if it's the best answer I could have given in Python 3.

Sample code:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> 
>>> myList = [1,1,2,3,4,5,3,2,3,4,2,1,2,3]
>>> print Counter(myList)
Counter({2: 4, 3: 4, 1: 3, 4: 2, 5: 1})
>>>
>>> print Counter(myList).items()
[(1, 3), (2, 4), (3, 4), (4, 2), (5, 1)]
>>> 
>>> print Counter(myList).keys()
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> 
>>> print Counter(myList).values()
[3, 4, 4, 2, 1]
```

> Task:
>
> Raghu is a shoe shop owner. His shop has X number of shoes. He has a
>   list containing the size of each shoe he has in his shop. There are N
>   number of customers who are willing to pay \$X_i\$ amount of money
>   only if they get the shoe of their desired size.
>
> Calculate how much Raghu earned.
>
> Input format:
>
> The first line contains the number of shoes.
>
> The second line contains the space separated list of all the shoe
>   sizes in the shop.
>
> The third line contains N, the number of customers.
>
> The next N lines contain the space separated values of the shoe size
>   desired by the customer and X<sub>i</sub>, the price of the shoe.
>
> Output format:
>
> Print the amount of money earned by Raghu.
>
> Sample input:
>
> ```
> 10
> 2 3 4 5 6 8 7 6 5 18
> 6
> 6 55
> 6 45
> 6 55
> 4 40
> 18 60
> 10 50
> ```
>
> Sample output:
>
> ```
> 200
> ```

Is this good? Where can I improve?

```
from collections import Counter
for _ in range(2):
    shoes = map(int, input().strip().split())
shoes = Counter(shoes)
income = 0
for _ in range(int(input())):
    query = list(map(int, input().split()))
    if query[0] in shoes and shoes[query[0]] > 0:
        shoes[query[0]] -= 1
        income += query[1]
print(income)
```

Comment: Please 1) Check your indentation (Control-K helps) 2) State only code-purpose in the title 3) Use quotation mark-up for the problem statement and provide a link back to the original for attribution.

Comment: As every single on-topic question on this site could have this exact same title (it's implied, *we review your code*), please [edit] the title to state the task that your code accomplishes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Repetition

Except the additional `list` these lines are identical:

```
shoes = map(int, input().strip().split())

query = list(map(int, input().split()))
```

You can write a function:

```
def read_integers_from_line(line):
    """
    >>> list(read_integers_from_line("12 3 7"))
    [12, 3, 7]
    """
    return map(int, line.strip().split())
```

That you can use twice.

#### Tuple unpacking

Instead of `query = read_integers_from_line(input())` you can use: `shoe, price = read_integers_from_line(input())` so that the code becomes more self-descriptive.

#### Skipping the first line

The first line contains useless information, you skip it weirdly using a `range` but I would suggest a more explicit skip by using instead `_ = input()`

Comment: Can you please edit my code and answer again?

Comment: **`from collections import Counter
def read():
    return map(int, input().strip().split())

_ = input()
shoes = Counter(read())
income = 0

for _ in range(int(input())):
    size,price = list(read())
    if size in shoes and shoes[size] > 0:
        shoes[size] -= 1
        income += price

print(income)`**

Comment: @JøêGrèéñ what do you mean? You should  modify your code yourself, I cannot touch it as determined by site policies